# Cant break loop using button

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, button, break

I wanted make window which will reappear if closed but will only close if user presses a button. I tried so many times but cant make. Plz help.

```py
from Tkinter import *
x='y'
while x!='break':
    def something(x):
        x='break'
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    button=tkinter.Button(root, text='Break', command=lambda:something(x))
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
print('done')
```

Comment: Add `global x` at the start of your `something` function. You might also want to add `root.destroy()` in that function.

Comment: No i cant add global x command interpreter says that 'x is parameter and global'

Comment: Then remove the `x` from `lambda:something(x)` and `def something(x)`

Comment: Oh thank u mahn stuck in this problem since months

Comment: U can if u want u will get badge and reputation and stuff and another can also see solution ur wish but thank u so much. Upvote is u want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `x` using `x = "break"`, you set the local variable which means that the global variable `x` is still `"y"`. So to solve your problem just make sure that you use the global variable for `x`. This is a simple example:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def something():
    # Use the global variable for `loop_running`
    global loop_running
    loop_running = False
    # You might also want to add: root.destroy()

loop_running = True

while loop_running:
    root = tk.Tk()
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Break", command=something)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()

print("Done")
```